# how to extract specific info from Soap response in Python (pysimplesoap)

Tags: python, soap, xml-parsing, pysimplesoap

I'm starting to code in python using pysimplesoap. Testing first against a service available on Internet. I'm stuck trying to parse the result of the Soap query.
I coded:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
import pysimplesoap
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

client=SoapClient(wsdl="http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl",trace=True)
response = client.VerifyEmail(email="a-valid-gmail-address@gmail.com",LicenseKey="?")
print response
```

I get the following which means the Soap request was positive:

```
{'VerifyEmailResult': {'GoodEmail': True, 'LastMailServer': u'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 'ResponseText': u'Mail Server will accept email', 'ResponseCode': 3}}
```

I now want to extract the value of GoodEmail which is equal to True from "response" and store it in a variable named "result".
I tried various things, without success.
I must admit I'm very new to Python, and would appreciate help from a knowledgeable person!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get as the response is a Python `dict`. You can access the `GoodEmail` value like that:

```
result = response['VerifyEmailResult']['GoodEmail']
```

You can read more about Python data types here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that. Anyway it's exactly what I was looking for. I would have rated your answer but i can't because I don't have 15 points of rating yet.